# Seeder, ошибка при вставке json-данных

Tags: laravel

Есть таблица с колонкой `properties`, содержащей `json-данные`

```
$table->json('properties')->nullable();
```

В файле `Seeder` нужно добавить `json-данные`

```
$sections = [
    [
        'name' => 'section1',
        'content' => 'content1',
        'properties' => json_encode([
            "link" => "/link"
        ]),
    ],
...
DB::table('sections')->insert($sections);
```

но при импорте данных выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 2
```

Если убрать `json_encode` то выдаёт ошибку:

```
 Array to string conversion
```

Как правильно вставлять `json-данные` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

первая ошибка пишет что количество вставляемых значений не соответствует количеству столбцов.
Похоже что у вас дальше ошибка, не в первом массиве данных.
проверьте весь массив данных

вторая ошибка все верно. нужно делать кодирование массива.

Я обычно делаю вставку данных через модель
`Sections::create($section)` в которой описано что данное поле json, и поле в этом случае не кодирую а оставляю массивом. и никаких проблем нет.